# How can I drop second Primary Key in MVC model?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have model that has 2 primary key. I wanna drop one of them but I got an error.

My Model;

```
public class Equipment
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public int EquipmentId { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I wanna drop Name columns' key.

```
public class Equipment
        {
            [Key]
            public int EquipmentId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try that, I got an error like;

**'FK_dbo.Employee_Equipment_dbo.Equipments_Equipments_EquipmentId_Equipments_Name' is not a constraint.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.**

Answer (score 0):

Use should remove from DB incorrect data. For your data you should delete all repeat EquipmentID row.

Comment: Did you remove constraint from DB ?